# Default Show Left Bar Button Item

Tags: swift2

I am using a show segue from a Table View cell to a "Detail View" because I am using a navigation controller, the Detail View comes by default with a left bar button to take me back to Table View. Because it is done by default, I cannot figure out how to access it, to change its propertys. More specifically it's color. I am using Swift in the most current Xcode. How do you access the default navigation bar button when using a show segue?

Comment: can u show some code?

Comment: I wish I could. There is no code involved. VC1 is embedded in a Navigation Controller, VC1 uses Show Segue to access VC2. All done in storyboard. VC2 comes with a Default "Back" button in the Nav Bar. Doesnt show up in code or storyboards. But when you run the app and use the segue, you see the button in VC2.

Comment: what do u mean with "Because it is done by default"? It´s very hard to figure out, what´s going on. :-(

Comment: If you make 2 VC's and embed in a navigation controller with a "Show Segue" going from VC1 to VC2, you'll see in VC2 a back button. It does not show up in storyboards, nor does it show up in code (obviously.)

Comment: ok, that´s clear. And u did add nothing else?

Comment: No, do you know how to access the invisible Nav button in VC2?

Comment: no, i´m just trying to reproduce it... OR: much better: upload your project i.e. http://wikisend.com

Comment: so, now i´m tired. ;-) Will have a look tomorrow in the afternoon...

Comment: Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: i´m waiting, if u upload any source...